# In Need of Recommendations on How to Easily/Efficiently Fill In/Import Missing Data on CommCare Application

Tags: commcare

I have a CommCare application that our team has already launched for data collection. During the first round of data collection, we realized that we wanted to collect a few more variables and implemented a change through CommCare to add those variables. As a result, new columns were added to the data exports, and data is missing for the new variables for respondents who were interviewed prior to the change. Data collectors collected data for the new variables in their notebooks for respondents that were interviewed prior to the change.

I was wondering if there was an easy way to transfer the missing data to CommCare through an Excel import. It seems that updating cases by importing and Excel file only updates the case properties.

Any input regarding this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting to update the form data as well?

The only updates that can be made to form data are edits to the existing fields. This can only be done via the UI. It is not possible to add new fields to an existing form submission.

For cases you can update existing properties and add new properties via the Excel importer. There are some system properties that you can not update but the majority of case properties can be edited.